# git merge hash name conflicts -> line whitelist possible?

Tags: git

I use automatic file hashing with relative html generation. The hashed file names generate constant conflict. Is it possible to omit certain lines of code from git conflict checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You can assign custom merge drivers to some files using the gitattributes mechanism, but then you also need to define the merge driver (which involves changing your .git/config) and actually implement it. Your driver would have to implement standard merge logic and special treatment for those generated lines.

More details in the official manpage: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_performing_a_three_way_merge

The general recommendation for Git is to avoid putting generated content in tracked files altogether. Possibly a scheme in which the tracked file has placeholders and the hashes are generated and inserted in an untracked copy of the file is a viable alternative for you...